# how to get the numbers pressed in the dial up screen using android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to android .. and I'm trying to get the numbers that are pressed in the dial up screen once the user press some sequence of numbers and before he presses the call button..

Answer (score 0):

You can use onKeyDown method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0){

        // note this if called
    }else if(keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1){
    // note this if called  
    }else if(keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2){
    // note this if called  
    }else if(keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3){
    // note this if called  
    }elseif(keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4){
    // note this if called  
    }else....
        .....
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: No permissions in manifest for this method dear...this is Override method provided in every Activity.

Comment: I want this to work with built in dial up screen, so it should be receiver in the manifest and not activity